# Animating backgroundColor doesn't work in jQuery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, animation, colors, background

I have the following code.

```
   $("[id^=menuItem]").mouseenter(function () {
      $(this).animate({ width: 400, backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);
   });
```

When i hover with the mouse, the regarded div does get wider BUT there is no change in the beckground color (it differs from black, of course). What can be the problem? I try to follow the suggestion at the following link, the example of which indeed seem to work.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ColorAnimations

Comment: Have you added [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) library?

Comment: No, i have not, for the reasons discussed below.   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The jQuery UI effects core extends the animate function to be able to animate colors as well.

You'll need to include the jQuery UI library before you can do this.

Comment: I thought jQuery UI was an internal part of jQuery (jQ is after all a UI-library, so it made sense to me). I'll be off adding jQUI right away and let's hope that'll do the trick.

Comment: It worked perfectly! I only had to copy jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css with the images directory to my project and voila! Personally i think that such functionality SHOULD be in the core of jQuery but i guess it has to do with the file size...